# XBOX ONE controller inputs vanish in project settings

Tags: unity, input, controllers

I'm putting in the inputs for the XBOX ONE controller in Project settings, but when I try to put in the values for the triggers and click on the next window, that value vanishes. I'm putting the value in **Positive Button**. I then tried it in the Negative with the same result.

I checked the spelling, axis and everything looks fine, so I'm unsure why it's suddenly vanishing and not letting me input a value.

Here is the input for the right trigger:
[image]

Now when I put in the axis for the right trigger, like this:
[image]

And I press enter, or click away, it clears the field like this:
[image]

After setting it up as an axis, it's still not working:
[image]

And setting the type to axis:
[image]

Any idea on why it's doing this?

Comment: You're still not following instructions. You did not set the Type field to "Joystick Axis" and you did not modify the Gravity/Dead/Sensitivity fields as shown in the answer below. It's going to take much longer to solve your problem if you don't take the time to read answers thoroughly and follow every step they tell you to take.

Comment: @DMGregory I have tried this before and it did not work. That's why I tried treating it as a button, but even when set up as an axis, it simply won't work. By this point, I'm certain it's a bug, because no matter what angle I approach this problem, how many tutorials I follow, or who I ask for help, this trigger does not want to work. I know it shouldn't be my controller, since it's XBOX ONE and everything shows it having the same set up as an Xbox 360 controller. I'm really stumped and I do read answers repeatedly to make sure I'm following them.

Comment: Every example you've shown in this question is set up wrong, so we can't verify that you're encountering a new bug rather than a setup error. Can you show us an example where you've set up the axis correctly, and read it correctly using Input.GetAxis()?

Answer (score 0):

"Right Trigger" is not one of the button names Unity knows how to check. Neither is the number 10.

[These special names that Unity looks for are listed in the docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html):

> - Normal keys: “a”, “b”, “c” …
> - Number keys: “1”, “2”, “3”, … Arrow    keys: “up”, “down”, “left”, “right”
> - Keypad keys: “[1]”, “[2]”, “[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85P4G.png)”,    “[+]”, “[equals]”
> - Modifier keys: “right shift”, “left shift”, “right    ctrl”, “left ctrl”, “right alt”, “left alt”, “right cmd”, “left cmd”
> - Mouse Buttons: “mouse 0”, “mouse 1”, “mouse 2”, …
> - Joystick Buttons    (from any joystick): “joystick button 0”, “joystick button 1”,    “joystick button 2”, …
> - Joystick Buttons (from a specific joystick):    “joystick 1 button 0”, “joystick 1 button 1”, “joystick 2 button 0”,    …
> - Special keys: “backspace”, “tab”, “return”, “escape”, “space”,    “delete”, “enter”, “insert”, “home”, “end”, “page up”, “page down”
> - Function keys: “f1”, “f2”, “f3”, …

**The left/right triggers are not buttons at all**, but axes. Axis 9 & 10 specifically, on Windows. [You can find the mapping between buttons/axes and their joystick-indexed slots here](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Xbox360Controller).

To configure an axis like the analog sticks or triggers, **you do not type anything at all into the "Positive Button" field**. Because, again, they are not buttons. Instead, set the input type to Joystick Axis and select the axis number from the "Axis" dropdown near the bottom of the inspector for this input, as shown in this screenshot of a right trigger mapped control:

[image: Screenshot of Unity Input manager showing configuration of the right trigger as described above]

Note that the "Positive Button" field is deliberately left blank, and the axis is specified in the drop-down at the bottom. Axes typically also use lower gravity and sensitivity than buttons, with a larger dead range, but this is something you can tune for feel.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: "Didn't work" is never enough information to diagnose a problem. What specific steps did you take, and what specific outcome did you observe?

Comment: I found out I was spelling them wrong (and that's entirely on me) but now I'm having trouble assigning the Dpad's individual arrows and the triggers. I've checked my spelling and mapping from what you showed me but the 10th axis vanishes like before, so I'm wondering if it's a bug with Unity itself P:

What do you think?

Comment: Again, an axis is not a button, so you do not write it in the "Positive Button" text field. You set the type to Joystick Axis and select the axis in the dropdown

Comment: I have done this, but it still vanishes. I think it may be a bug, because I've followed so many tutorials, diagrams and asked around but still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What specific content vanishes from what specific field?

Comment: In the input field, for an axis, normally you can put in a number and it will assign. For some reason, if I try to put in the 10th axis (just as a 10) for the right trigger and press enter or click away, that input of 10 vanishes.

I cannot figure out why it's doing this though, as I've seen no one else have this issue and I know the controller is fine.

Comment: There is no field here called *Input" do you mean the drop-down labelled "Axis"? This is not a text field you type into.

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots to show the exact problem.

Comment: Just to repeat: DO NOT TYPE INTO THE "POSITIVE BUTTON" FIELD IF YOU ARE CONFIGURING AN AXIS. That's not how you set up an axis. Use the axis drop-down at the bottom. Ignore the "Positive Button" field entirely. It is not for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, I've cleared it and set it up, however it's still not working. I'll add a screenshot to the question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble without reimplementing the wheel – use a proven, established controller plugin like [InControl](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/incontrol-14695) or [Rewired](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676).